# How can I avoid typing the full namespace hierarchy for c# objects in Monodevelop ("using" isn't working)?

Tags: c#, import, namespaces, monodevelop

I have a hierarchy of namespaces like `My.Namespace.MyObject` in a library. My understanding is that if I include `using My.Namespace;` at the top of a source file that I should be able to use `Object` directly. Unfortunately, it only works if I type out the entire `My.Namespace.MyObject`, neither `Namespace.MyObject` nor `MyObject` alone will work. In trying to research this I've found that it can happen when classes and namespaces share names but this is not the case for me. It's really hard to Google for "using not working" so I haven't been able to find much else that might be relevant.

A full example is as follows. In one project I do:

```
namespace My {
   namespace Namespace {
       public struct MyObject {}
   }
}
```

Then I build this which produces a dll file. In a second project I add the dll as a reference and then do:
using My.Namespace;

```
public class AnotherObject
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      //results in a compilation error, while My.Namespace.MyObject doesn't
      MyObject a;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using the name `Object`, basically - I suspect the problem is that you're also importing the `System` namespace, containing `System.Object`. If `Object` was just an unfortunately-chosen example name, please include a [mcve] with the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: @Ivanna, please refer to this [MSDN C# KeyWords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) documentation in regards to naming conventions this will save you a lot of re-write in the future if you ever have to change your classes to more meaningful names.

Comment: That's not the actual naming, I meant it to be a generic term for an object.

Answer (score 0):

Project A, compiled into `LibraryTest.dll`:

```
namespace FirstLevel
{
    namespace SecondLevel 
    {
        public class LibraryClass
        {
            public LibraryClass()
            {
            }

            static void Main() 
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Project B, just a console app, using Project A library:

```
using FirstLevel.SecondLevel;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            LibraryClass test = new LibraryClass();
        }
    }
}
```

**Important: Make sure your library is added to `References` in the other project**

- right click on `References` -> `Edit References...`
- switch to `.NET Assembly`
- click on `Browse...`
- select your library

See also attached screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Two files within the same project work fine, the issue is when I import a library in Monodevelop. I'm guessing that it might have something to do with build options or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I didn't read your post properly enough... I just did another test, with a library now, see my edited answer.